# Mvc pre-populate a date field with data that will link to the model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I want to create a form that will create a new item but that will pre-populate some data, espcially the date which I want to be `DateTime.Now` and eventually link this data with the model, without leaving the option of my user to modify it.

So far here's what I have done:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
{
    var currentDate = DateTime.Now;
    Model.m_OrderDate = currentDate;
}   
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)
(...)
Order Date: @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.m_OrderDate)<br/>

<p>
    <input type="submit" value="Create" />
</p>
</fieldset>
```

But the app crashes on runtime at the line `Model.m_OrderDate = currenDate` saying that `Object reference is not set to an instance of an object.`

I've looked through for many solutions but have yet to solve it. Can anyone help me? Thanks a lot!

Comment: It seems that your Model object is null - are you initializing it in the controller?

Comment: I just saw the same thing as you did, Jarimba. Nope, it is not initialized in the controller. So far, in my "Create" views, I do not initialize anything, but I will try and do so. Good point!

Comment: Simple as that. Thank you @RuiJarimba!

Answer (score 1):

In your model:

```
private DateTime? orderDate = null;
public DateTime OrderDate
{
    get { return orderDate ?? DateTime.Now; }
    set { orderDate = value; }
}
```

The only other piece is to make sure you pass an initialized model to your GET views, i.e.:

```
public ActionResult MyAwesomeView()
{
    return View(new MyModel());
}
```

The default will automatically populate.